# Executing Java Cucumber feature files one by one from bash script and continue execution of feature files after first one has completed

Tags: java, bash, cucumber

I have a need to run a bunch of Java cucumber feature files, one by one, by using a bash script on MacOS High Sierra. The problem I have is, as soon as the first feature file is done executing (either success or failure), the Cucumber framework does its reporting on that feature file and my script does not execute the remaining feature files. It "returns" to the command line.

Here is part of the script that runs the cucumber files one by one:

```
function run_cucumber_features {
  for file in $(find ./src/test  -name '*Steps.feature' -print0 | xargs -0);
    do gradle cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options="$file" DmutationTesting="false" -DmutationParameter="$parameter";
  done
}
```

For example, let's say I execute my script:

```
./mutation_testing.sh
```

The script then invokes Cucumber and the first feature the script finds execute, and then it 'exits' with the status code for that specific feature:

```
BUILD Success in 18s
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 5 succeeded
```

However, it then does not proceed to execute the next feature file, it returns to the command line:

```
username$
```

My question is whether there is a way for my script to not stop executing once Cucumber has done its reporting after every feature file that has been executed?

Comment: As a first quick check amend your script from `... do gradle ...` to `... do echo gradle ...` to check that the loo find all expected files. When this returns what you expect you might add at the beginning of your script `set -x` to see which steps the Bash script executes and probably this reveals already why it exit after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I added "do echo gradle", and that returned all the expected files.

Comment: Adding "set -x", reveals that it executes up until:  do gradle cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options="$file" DmutationTesting="false" -DmutationParameter="$parameter", after which it invokes Cucumber and then it never returns to the script.

Comment: Please have a look to my answer, as it was to long as a comment. You might investigate yourself your Bash script / Gradle build file or post it here. Best would be to post as much code as needed for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: SubOptimal's advise of removing, "set -e" from the script, fixed the issue. Control is now not returned, and all the feature files execute as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be related to the steps inside your `build.gradle` file or the way you call the function in the Bash script.

A small test set-up. Assume the following structure#!/bin/bash

```
run-gradle-loop.sh                    # executable script
gradle                                # executable script, as simple replacement
src/test/subdir/file2_Steps.feature   # a dummy file
src/test/file1_Steps.feature          # a dummy file
```

**run-gradle-loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_cucumber_features {
  for file in $(find ./src/test  -name '*Steps.feature' -print0 | xargs -0);
  do
    gradle cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options="$file" DmutationTesting="false" -DmutationParameter="$parameter";
    echo "return code = $?"
  done
}

# to run the gradle script in the current directory
export PATH=$(pwd):${PATH}

run_cucumber_features
```

**gradle**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo "running gradle dummy"
echo "passed parameters : $@"

# exit with an error code
exit 1
```

**file1_Steps.feature** and **file2_Steps.feature** are two empty files, only to fulfill the loop criteria.

The aim of the test is to check the behavior where `gradle` exit with an error code.

run the main Bash script

```
./run-gradle-loop.sh
```

output

```
running gradle dummy
passed parameters : cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options=./src/test/subdir/file2_Steps.feature DmutationTesting=false -DmutationParameter=
return code = 1

running gradle dummy
passed parameters : cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options=./src/test/file1_Steps.feature DmutationTesting=false -DmutationParameter=
return code = 1
```

This shows that even `gradle` would return with an error code the loop processes all `.*Steps.feature` files.

**edit** One way it might stop after the first error could be that in the `run-gradle-loop.sh` script there is a `set -e` statement.

`man bash`

> -e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list,  or  a  compound  command

Which means. When the script `gradle` fails with an error the control is not returned to `run-gradle-loop.sh`. The output with above set-up would be

```
$ ./run-gradle-loop.sh

running gradle dummy
passed parameters : cucumberTest -Dcucumber.options=./src/test/subdir/file2_Steps.feature DmutationTesting=false -DmutationParameter=
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I just removing, "set -e" from the script, which fixed the issue. Control is now not returned, and all the feature files execute as expected. Thank you!

Comment: PS, well done for thinking that "set -e" could be present in my script, as I never posted the entire script.

Comment: @kosielr Seems I should use my crystal ball more often. ;-) Nice to hear that your issue is solved.